# Make button act as span in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the form below, in which I have a search glyphicon inside the input.

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to make my glyphicon submit my form, but for that I'd have to change the span for a input or button. In either way, the glyphicon goes outside the input and displays below it. I couldn't figure out why yet. I was able to put it in the correct position through absolute positioning, but it is not good for the way it is displayed in the website. Is there any way to solve this problem only with css and without absolute positioning?

Comment: have you tried a type=submit button and css reset ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrbYQa

Comment: I have and couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is bootstrap style buttons and inputs differently. You can use `<span>` and submit form with `onclick` event.
See this code:

```
<form id="myForm" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon btn" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q76dasdk/

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to have a good way to do it css-only. I'm going to go with this instead. Thanks.